# Makefile hangs when docker-compose -d is used and fails with code 129 without -d

Tags: docker, drupal, makefile, drush

for reference, my rule looks like this:

```
aRule:
    docker-compose exec -d service /bin/bash -c "/path/to/drush -y drush-commmand"
```

On Ubuntu 16.04 and 14.04, if I run a command such as `docker-compose exec -d service /bin/bash -c "/path/to/drush -y drush-commmand` in a Makefile rule, Makefile hangs and then fails due to MemoryError from the docker container.  This command, however, works in both centos and docker-machine.

I try to substitute the command with `docker-compose exec service /bin/bash -c "path/to/drush -y drush-command` (without the -d flag) and this time the drush command succeeds, however the Makefile fails with error code `129`.

I then try to rectify the issue with the modified command, `docker-compose exec service /bin/bash -c "path/to/drush -y drush-command 1>/dev/null"`, this works... but seems a bit hack-ish

What is the correct way of doing this and why am I getting the aforementioned errors?

Comment: I have the same issue and I found a no pretty solution by using `-T` parameter, ex `docker-compose exec -T app php -r `